# Android collections, which should i use?

Tags: java, android, arrays, collections, multidimensional-array

Just making a little android app, and I need to hold a collection of data, and not sure if I should use an object, array, listarray, hashmap, etc.

It needs to be able to store strings and integers (eg tamename, score, category, number of turns).

It needs to be able to store a variable number of teams.

Currently having issues where I try to store it as an object, but it wont lt me increment the score int value.

Which collection should I use for this instance, and when should I use each one in other instances?

**EDIT**

Ok so did that, but I keep getting NullPointerException when i try to access / increment it. I can only assume it cant access the teams var properly from upScore

So my onCreate is like this

```
public ArrayList<Team> teams;
public int currentTeam;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    currentTeam = 0;

    List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    teams.add(new Team("Team 1"));
    teams.add(new Team("Team 2"));

}
```

then upScore gets called when a button is pressed. the fatal exception is on this line

```
public void upScore(int team_key) {
    teams.get(0).score++;
}
```

And here is my Team object

```
class Team {
    public String name;
    public int score;
    public String category;
    public int turns;

    public Team (String teamName) {
        name = teamName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Store in objects of class Team, Match, Play?

Comment: I'd recommend you some reading before being able to choose the appropriate collection. When you know advantages of each of them you'll understand which one suits you the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own class that represents objects which can hold the data you need, something like:

```
class Team
{
    public String teamName;
    public int score;
    public String category;
    public int numberOfTurns;

    public Team(...){...} // the constructor
}
```

Then use any data structure you want, for example, an arraylist:

```
List<Team> list = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

To add elements to the list:

```
list.add(new Team(...));
```

To increment the score of the first team in the list:

```
list.get(0).score++;
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Change

`List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();`

to

`teams = new ArrayList<Team>();`

See: [Your declarations is hiding the member variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777908/java-beginner-if-else-if-problem/6777971#6777971)

Comment: Please also consider using private variables instead of public.

Comment: accepted answer goes to @Eng.Fouad for getting me 90% of the way there, but rep++ for you too :) thx!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.